# How I can solder back this ribbon cable from my alarm clock?

Tags: soldering

An ribbon cable out of my alarm clock has been cut as image shows:

[image: Ribbon cable of my alarm clock]

That was attached to this piece of an another pcb:

Back:
[image: Place where was soldered]

Front:
[image: PCB where ribbon cable was soldered from the front]

And I want to solder it back. How I can do this?

Comment: have you looked at the pictures before you posted them? ... why are you posting out of focus pictures?

Comment: remove the solder from the circuit board  ... strip the insulation from the end of the cable ... insert end of cable into the circuit board holes ... solder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That kind of flat cable is just extruded over (usually) stranded wires. You've bent it back and forth and fatigued those wires off.

Photo from Alibaba.com:
[image]

You need to use a solder sucker and clean the holes out (relatively easy with a single-sided  board) without damaging the traces or pads (relatively more difficult because it's a cheap paper-based phenolic with poor copper adhesion and no plated-through holes), then carefully use a knife to remove the insulation on the flat cable leaving about 5mm of bare wire in each position, without nicking the wires (in the factory they use a hot scraper- if you have some similar tool you might be able to use that- maybe a leather iron or something like that). Possibly a urethane type automatic stripper will work. Do not breath the fumes from hot plastic- it can contain chlorine since the insulation is usually PVC.

Insert the wires in the PCB (make sure you get the flat cable the right way 'round) and re-solder them. If you blow it or the flat cable is too short to fit, you can desolder both ends and use (seven it looks like) insulated wires.